# Spring batch- How to collect the items skipped and write it to xml file at the end of skiplimit

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am trying to collect the items which are skipped and **finally** want to create an errorsummary XML file to reprocess the errored items.

```
 @Override
public void onSkipInProcess(Object o, Throwable throwable) {
    log.error("Exception encountered while processing the item"+throwable.getMessage()+throwable.getCause());
    if(o instanceof File)
    {
        File f = (File) o;
        if(errorReportSummary!=null)
        {
            int filesCount = errorReportSummary.getFilesCount();
            filesCount++;
            errorReportSummary.setFilesCount(filesCount);
            errorReportSummary.getFiles().getFiles().add(f);
        }else
        {
               errorReportSummary = new ReportSummary();
               errorReportSummary.setFilesCount(1);
               errorReportSummary.getFiles().getFiles().add(f);

        }
    }
```

I am collecting the item here and storing it in an object which I want to save as an XML in S3 once the skip limit is reached. But I am not sure how to identify the skip limit reach. I thought to use skip policy but that doesn't have the item passed.

Please suggest. Thank you

Comment: Do you really need to collect items and only write them at the end when the skip limit is reached? Why not writing them on the fly to the file and when the skip limit is reached and the job fails, you send the file afterwards with a `JobExecutionListener#afterJob` for example.

Comment: okay,  where should I write the on the fly to move it to S3 at the end ?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine right now- I have a counter in skiplistener and incrementing it for every skip. and once it reaches the configured skipcount, I am writing the file to the source. will that be ok ?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine One more suggestion please.,  I have composite processor and one of the proceesor is rest call and its the last one. the response of the rest is sent to writer.  If the writer fails for somereason, how do I configure to retry writer step alone? I am thinking to save the writer input to a file and have a sepeaate step to read the input and call the writer ? will that be ok or any better suggestions ? thank you

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine any suggestions please ?

Comment: I got it, I will add the reportsummary to jobexecutioncontext and write to s3 at last instead of count.

Comment: Yes, that can work. You can do it in a job listener as I said initially or in a final step. In  regards to `I have composite processor and one of the proceesor is rest call and its the last one. the response of the rest is sent to writer. If the writer fails for somereason, how do I configure to retry writer step alone?`: This is an interesting question, please open a separate question for that I and I will try to help.